# spring-boot @WebIntegrationTest is secured by default

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot, integration-testing

I'm relatively new to spring-boot and now I would like to write some integration tests for my first application.

My application provides several REST webservices, the main application starts like this

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@RestController
@SpringBootApplication
public class DistributorWebserviceApplication implements
    ApplicationContextAware {..}
```

The application itself seems to be properly configured but in the integration test the webservice endpoints are secured and one needs username and password!? I didn't configure this on purpose.

Integration test class

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = DistributorWebserviceApplicationIntegrationTestConfiguration.class)
@WebIntegrationTest("server.port=0")
public class DistributorWebserviceApplicationIntegrationTest {..}
```

Spring configuration

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Configuration
public class DistributorWebserviceApplicationIntegrationTestConfiguration {..}
```

Calling a webservice in a test method like

```
String url = String.format("http://localhost:%s%s", serverPort,
    DistributorWebserviceApplication.URL_QUEUE_DISTRIBUTOR_JOB);
String result = restTemplate.postForObject(url, distributorJob,
    String.class);
```

produces the result
    {"timestamp":1431006031152,"status":401,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"Full authentication is required to access this resource","path":"/queueDistributorJob"}

Is there any possibility to disable the default security configuration?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you wanting to disable Spring Security for the application too or only for only testing?

Comment: @RobWinch I want to disable Spring Security for the integration testing. In the application Spring Security is configured and works as expected.

Comment: "In the application Spring Security is configured and works as expected." means what? You need username/password to access that particular endpoint or not?

Comment: The REST webservice methods are secured by spring-security using IP filters. In the tests there is a basic authentication for all REST webservice methods - probably because spring-security is found in the classpath.